# Same values in a dependent variable

Tags: regression

Can we predict through multiple regression if the dependent value is always 1 and there are some quantitative and qualitative independent variables?

Comment: The independent variables can't tell you anything more than the model "the DV is always 1". You might regard that as 'can predict', but you can't argue that the IVs contribute anything.

Comment: Related to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102970/)? Suggest you read 
[How to ask a Statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) & concentrate on the first point - describing your problem before trying to frame it in statistical terms. I got the impression that the real question might have been to do with how to aggregate data sensibly before defining a model.

Comment: Yes, the question is regarding how to gather data before applying the model...any suggestions on this or any reading?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you read 
[How to ask a Statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/).

Comment: Sorry if that sounded testy, but I feel there's a basic question underlying this, which you'll likely get useful advice on if only you ask it.

Answer (score 3):

No. Because the model with intercept only will explain all the variation in the dependent variable. No variation, no model.

Comment: +1. But I would have answered "Yes" in the sense that an intercept-only model is still a case of multiple regression. Moreover, including the other IVs will still yield the same result.